# Video call solution for android

Tags: android, video, sdk

I am looking for a video call solution for android. Tried using [tokbox](https://tokbox.com) but there solution has lot of limitations e.g. Android 4.0+, and doesn't support 64 bit phones.

Implemented my own solution using WebRTC, but since video is not my game don't want to support backend servers for myself.

Also, [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/guide/quickstart-android) is coming up with a solution in 6-8 weeks (beta). But I really cannot wait till then.

Preferably trying to find solution which provides android/ios/web sdk (preferably) and backend server solution for it. Any help / research done on same is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need servers if you decide to build  your own WebRTC implementation, you can always use separate services; for the signaling part you could use [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/), for the TURN servers you can use [XirSys](http://xirsys.com/). 
You might still need to compile the WebRTC code for the different platforms depending on your needs, that does require some work but it is definitely faster than waiting for Twilio.

TokBox is by far the easiest way, at this moment, to accomplish what you want. Even if you wait for Twilio you might find yourself with similar limitations.

Finally, if you really don't want to get your hands dirty by using your own WebRTC implementation [webrtc.ventures](http://webrtc.ventures/) offer development software services. Small disclaimer: I work there :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented [QuickBlox](http://quickblox.com) solution in my application. They provide good quality video call features with very good pricing. You may get the idea of implementation from their sample applications also https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk

Comment: hey, which application? I'll give it a shot. Also, how easy was the integration? any major limitations they have?

Answer (score 0):

```
Refer to the following links.
```

Download Android SDK from this link
  http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads

and follow the steps mentioned in the below link 
  http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html#.ViOKwLJ97IU -- for Android

Hopefully this will help...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html

You can find opensource SIP servers, able to host your own and try to learn SIP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested you using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) & [socket.io](http://socket.io) package. 
I hope this links helpful for you:

http://gingertech.net/2013/02/06/video-conferencing-in-html5-webrtc-via-socket-io/

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/socket.io/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nG7OhBnfefE